# Using IEnumerable<T> as an input to a method

Tags: c#, generics

The following code produces an error on the generic T, and I don't understand why. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong, and what the proper way to do it is?

Code:

```
public static class CSVWriter
{
    public static void WriteData(string fileName, string path, IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        string filePath = path + fileName + ".csv";
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Create(filePath).Close();
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(data.ToString());
        }

        File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Error CS0246
The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it

```
public static class CSVWriter
{
    public static void WriteData<T>(string fileName, string path, IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        string filePath = path + fileName + ".csv";
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            File.Create(filePath).Close();
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(data.ToString());
        }

        File.AppendAllText(filePath, sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

`T` is a type parameter. Your method or your class should declare it. If you opt to declare `T` as a type parameter of your method, you write your method as `WriteData<T>`.

Notice that you could, also, declare `T` as a type parameter of your class, but, in this case, your class should not be `static`, because you would need to instantiate it. If you wanted to do this, that's how you would do it:

```
public class CSVWriter<T> { ... }
```

For more information, please refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx